# How to trigger an animation qml when a value from C++ change?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have an application which use C++ and QML.

In my C++ : I read the ***value*** and i send it to QML in order to show it in a slider.
My ***value*** change when i press in my hardware.

My problem is in the QML part:

In QML :

I need to trigger an animation for few seconds when this ***value*** change. I only need to show this animation when the value from c++ part Change.

if someone could help ?

I already tried the QML timer but not showing animation when value changed ?

Some code in QML part for the animation :

VolumeRemote.QML

```
Rectangle {
id: item1
width: 550
height: 110
color: "#0a0a07"
border.color: "#ffffff"
opacity: 1


SliderComponent{
    id:slider
    x: 34
    y: 79
    width: 466
    height: 5
    minimumValue: 0
   //here i give the value from C++ to my slider
   //Controller is a global Qobject where i define some stuff
    value: Controller.volume_radio
    onValueChanged: {
    animation.running=true;

 }

PropertyAnimation {
                id:myanimation
                running: true                 
                target:item1                
                property: 'visible'
                to: false                      
                duration: 10000 
                }
      }

Text {
    id: text1
    x: 93
    y: 16
    width: 170
    height: 41
    color: "#ffffff"
    text: qsTr("Radio Volume :")
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.family: regular.name
}

Text {
    id: valeurslider
    x: 277
    y: 16
    // x: 618
    //y: 45
    width: 24
    height: 41
    color: "#ffffff"
    text: slider.value
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    opacity: 0.45
    font.pixelSize: 30
    font.family: regular.name
}

Image {
    id: image1
    x: 34
    y: 16
    width: 44
    height: 41
    source: "assets/ic_sound_popup_on.png"
}
```

}

Comment: How did you pass the variable to QML? Usually properties passed from C++ to QML are notifiable.

Comment: You can define a custom signal in C++ that triggers, and handle it on the QML-Side to start the Animation.

Comment: i use this in C++ part to notify the value :  Q_PROPERTY(int RadioVolume READ getval NOTIFY val_signal )

Comment: Ok, so in QML you can use appropriate onPropertyChanged signal in QML.

Comment: in my QML part, i just need to call RadioVolume by doing for example : myobject.Radiovolume

Comment: the equation that i can't resolve is the animation.                                                    1 : How to use your onPropertyChanged singal in qml inside the animation       2 : What type of animation should i use : Timer or just PpropertyAnimation

Comment: You are using the signal correctly. The question is: Do you trigger it when you change the value?

Comment: And: The animation runs at the beginning and turns the visibility to false after 10 seconds. Do you turn it back somewhere?

Comment: No, i don't really know how to to trigger it by using my signal Onval_signal and where to use it on my animation proprety.  if you have an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use @Beloqui  and @KevinKrammar second answer :

1 - Declare simple animation with property **visible**

2 - SliderCompenent and give the value : **Controller.volume_radio**

3 - use of connections in order to get the signal notified from C++ : *OnVolumesignal*

Then i can trigger the animation when signal is emitted from c++ part

Here a small piece of code :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.0
import Controllers 1.0
import "Logic.js" as Controller_Js

   Rectangle {
    id: item1
    width: 550
    height: 110
    color: "#0a0a07"
    border.color: "#ffffff"
   opacity: 1
   visible: Controller.stateVol

SliderComponent{
    id:slider
    x: 34
    y: 79
    width: 466
    height: 5
    minimumValue: 0
    maximumValue: 100
    value: Controller.volume_radio
  NumberAnimation {
    id: animation
    target: item1
    property: "visible"
    duration: 1000
    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
}

//gestion du signal
Connections{
    target:commodo
    onVolumesignal:{
        if (commodo.RadioVolume !==100){
            Controller.stateVol=true
            animation.start();
            console.log("state of controller :", Controller.stateVol)
        } else if (commodo.RadioVolume>100){
            animation.stop();
             Controller.stateVol=false
            console.log("state", Controller.stateVol)
        }
      }
  }
```

***Cobntroller.stateVol*** is defined to false in my **controller.qml**

Thanks guys, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

A local property and its change signal

```
readonly property qreal valueFromCpp: Controller.volume_radio
onValueFromCppChanged: // trigger animation
```

A Connections element

```
Connections {
    target: Controller
    onNameOfThePropertyNotifySignal:  // trigger animation
}
```

Comment: Any idea why having a declarative Controller.onVolume_radioChanged {} element doesn't work? It says Controller can't be found even though it works normally in other property bindings.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this in the C++ part: Q_PROPERTY(int RadioVolume READ getval NOTIFY val_signal ), you have to add a write function to change RadioVolume. Tha is to say:
Q_PROPERTY(int RadioVolume READ getval **WRITE setVal** NOTIFY val_signal ) and in the function setVal(), you have to change the RadioValume variable value and you have to emit the val_signal everytime the value changes. Instead of setting the value directly, call the setVal() function everywehre you set RadioVolume value and then in the QML part you have to put this:             **onVal_Signal:** put the animation here 
If you have any question regarding my answer do not hesitate to ask. If you have the code, i will be glad to help you change it

Comment: Thanks @JBerloqui, i resolve th first part of the problem And the value change. I will edit some code in QML part . The second problem will be how to trigger animation just for few seconds when value change and then it dissapears .

Comment: Can you post some code so i can help you with that part?

Comment: I see that you had added the code before i asked you for it! Sorry, i will read it and give you an answer